# ¿Qué tiene más prioridad, un script al final del body o un script en un documento aparte?

Tags: javascript, script

Si en un pagina web, dos sentencias están afectando al mismo elemento html y se contradicen, es decir, una da una orden con un valor y la otra la misma orden pero con otro valor, una ordena desde el body y la otra desde el documento .js... ¿cual tendria prioridad?

Comment: Tomara prioridad la que este declarada de ultimo; al final el valor se sobreescribe con la ultima funcion que se lee

Comment: No entiendo. Si tengo una sentencia al final del body y otra en una hoja aparte ¿cual machaca a la anterior?....es que creo que estoy teniendo ese problema.......¿te refieres a lineas? si la que esta al final del body esta en la linea 400 y la que esta en el .js esta en la linea 200 ¿la de 400 gana?

Comment: No, escribire una respuesta para explicar un poco mejor

Comment: Estas enfocando mal tu pregunta prioridad es cual se ejecuta primero,en este caso te refieres a cual script afecta al ultimo a tu elemento.

Comment: exacto ¿cual sobreescribe al otro?.como en css, que un estilo puesto en la misma etiqueta sobreescribe a la hoja de estilos o a la etiqueta style

Comment: @natan te sirvio alguna de las explicaciones?

Comment: El que el script esté en un documento aparte o no, no tiene ninguna importancia  para la **prioridad**. Generalmente los archivos se ponen aparte para tener el código más organizado (evitando un *totum revolutum*) o para fines de reusabilidad (por ejemplo un mismo archivo `.js` puede necesitarse en varios archivos del sistema). **La prioridad en sí depende del lugar en que incluyas el archivo o el código**. Por ejemplo, si en el encabezado incluyes un script que está en un archivo externo y en el footer incluyes código directo, tendrá prioridad el código que se incluyó en el encabezado.

Comment: Pero no entiendo..Si te fijas en las respuestas que me han dado, dicen que los scripts que van al final del body tienen prioridad, pero ahora tú me dices que el script del header tiene más prioridad que uno que ponga en el footer

Comment: Creo que aqui se estan empezando a confundir cosas de lexico... cuando decimos prioridad, no nos referimos a *Cual Script se ejecutara primero*... Sino a que, por ejemplo, si tienes un valor `X` en dos scripts, el valor final que tomara sera el que este declarado en el ultimo script

Comment: se podria decir "quien tiene mas peso" o "quien machaca al otro" o "quien tiene la ultima palabra"

Comment: Exacto, mira el ultimo ejemplo que acabo de incluir en mi respuesta

Comment: y es lo mismo si, en lugar de colocar el script directamente en las etiquetas head y body, se llamara a una hoja aparte, no??? o sea , si tu mismo ejemplo lo hicieras con hojas .js ¿seria igual no?.. porque la hoja es como si trasladaras todo su contenido a esa parte del html, no?

Comment: @natan exactamente igual; lo unico que estas modificando en esos casos es el *origen* del codigo, pero el mecanismo de lectura y ejecucion del documento funciona igual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El navegador lee el documento HTML de arriba hacia abajo, por tanto, cada hoja de estilos y/o script se ejecuta en orden descendente.

Digamos que tu documento HTML se ve asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var x = 15
          console.log(x)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

En este caso, la variable `x` siempre sera igual a 15; porque ese script es el ultimo en ser declarado, por ende, aunque en tu archivo externo `main.js` tengas otro valor y sea leido primero; al continuar leyendo el documento, al llegar al 2do script el valor cambia a 15 y este es el que termina ejecutandose.

Ahora, digamos que en tu HTML escribes el script antes de importar el archivo externo:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var x = 15
    </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Ahora, si tienes la misma funcion en `main.js`, es esta la que se termina ejecutando.

**PARA ACLARAR:** Si tienes un archivo externo, el navegador primero leera todo ese archivo antes de continuar al siguiente script; es por esto que no importa si tu archivo externo tiene 500 lineas y tu script en HTML tiene solo 5; el navegador primero leera las 500 lineas y luego seguira al otro script.

**EDIT:** 
Observa este ejemplo; declare 3 scripts en el documento HTML; uno esta en la etiqueta `head`, y los otros dos al final de la etiqueta `body`;

Al correr el fragmento; puedes ver que siempre se imprime en consola el valor que tiene el ultimo script que dice `var x = "Segundo Script en body"` ya que el documento se empieza a leer de arriba hacia abajo, para el momento en que se llega a ejecutar el script que dice `console.log(x)`, el ultimo valor de `x` que el navegador leyo es `Segundo script en body`; por tanto es ese ultimo el que se imprime, sin importar los valores anteriores.

```js
var x = 60
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = "Script en head"
  </script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = "Primer Script en body"
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = "Segundo Script en body"
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(x)
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91446/discussion-on-answer-by-ivans95-que-tiene-mas-prioridad-un-script-al-final-del).

Answer (score 0):

La prioridad la tendra el ultimo en ser declarado.

Ej: en este caso la accion no se realizará

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hacerAlgo.js">

<script>
    function noHacerAlgo(){}
</script>
```

Ej: en este caso la accion SI se realizará

```
<script>
    function noHacerAlgo(){}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hacerAlgo.js">
```

Comment: ¿y si el script externo fuera llamado desde el head?

Comment: No importa desde donde sea llamado. Si el externo lo llamas en el head se carga antes que el script que esta en el .html, por lo tanto este ultimo tendria la prioridad.

Comment: Hola. Para no abrir otro tema quisiera preguntar algo aqui, si fueras tan amable de responder: En cuanto a prioridad ya me quedo claro que el script final del body machaca a los otros scripts.....pero en cuanto a velocidad ¿cual es mas rapido, un script externo cargado en el head o un script al final del body (sea que este incrustado ahi mismo, o que se llame a un documento js desde el body)?